# In Sitecore Personalize, Why I can’t see any data in the operational tab for my Web Experience?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

When creating a web experience in `Sitecore Personalize` I want to see the experience executions in the operational tab. I can see my web experience executing on my website, but my executions aren't being shown in the operational tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see data in the operational tab for a `web experience/experiment` you need to set the point of sale in the settings where your `Sitecore CDP` JavaScript Library is being loaded.

```
    // Define the Boxever queue 
    var _boxeverq = _boxeverq || [];

    // Define the Boxever settings 
    var _boxever_settings = {
        client_key: '{{clientKey}}', // Replace with your client key
        target: '{{apiTargetEndpoint}}', // Replace with your API target endpoint specific to your data center region
        cookie_domain: '{{cookieDomain}}' // Replace with the top level cookie domain of the website that is being integrated e.g ".example.com" and not "www.example.com"
        web_flow_target:  "https://d35vb5cccm4xzp.cloudfront.net",
        pointOfSale: "{{pointOfSale}}"  // Replace with the point of sale you have configured in your tenant
};
    // Import the Boxever library asynchronously 
    (function() {
         var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true;  
         s.src = 'https://d1mj578wat5n4o.cloudfront.net/boxever-{{clientVersion}}.min.js';
         var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
```

When your `web experience/experiment` is executed an automatic stream event is sent in the **CDP** called a `TRACKING` event. The `TRACKING` event is the event that is used to update the operational tab. The point of sale that is populated on the `TRACKING` event relies on the point of sale setup in the settings.